# Function/variable auto completion C++ in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, autocomplete, xna, intellisense

I created 2 games using the visual studio 2010 for WP7 using XNA and when trying to create one using c++ in visual studio I dont know how to turn on the auto completion thing. When for example I wanted to write a function/variable, I just used to write the first  2 letters then choose it from the list. This helps me save time but I dont know how to turn this feature on when writing in c++

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> after typing a few letters.

Comment: Is there a way to make it automatic

Comment: Not natively, no. Visual Assist X can do that, but the license is quite costly.

Comment: What about refactor cpp I am downloading it right now and it is free but does do what I want?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're using C++/CLI, since you said both C++ and XNA (.NET).

Visual Studio 2010 doesn't have Intellisense for C++/CLI.  It should be added back in the next version, or you can buy Visual Assist X from Whole Tomato Software, which not only supports C++/CLI but does a better job on C# and native C++ as well.

If you don't intend to use .NET, you can get Intellisense working by turning off the `/clr` compiler option.

Comment: I want actually to develop games using Airplay SDK (Marmalade) which supports c++ so...

Comment: @user: Then make sure you have a native project, no `/clr`.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by no /clr

Comment: `/clr` is a compiler flag that enables the Common Language Runtime (managed code). Not specifying it on the command-line means you're using native code.